# Empty value (NA) in file.path function displays extra slash character

Tags: r

How can I represent an empty value in `file.path` function in R?

For example, in the `fileName` variable below, I want an output with one slash character `"C:/Temp/abc.pdf"` instead of two `"C:/Temp//abc.pdf"`.

```
condition <- TRUE
fileName <- file.path("C:/Temp", ifelse(condition, "", "Approved"), "abc.pdf")
fileName
[1] "C:/Temp//abc.pdf"
```

Replacing `""` with `NA`, `character(0)` or `NULL` did not work.

The file path resulted can be used without any problem in any file manipulation function (i.e. `file.exists`, `file.copy` etc.). It is more like a visual issue (I want to copy the output path manually without replacing double slashes to Windows Explorer for example).

p.s. I prefer not to use string replacement.

Comment: Can you just use the `paste` function? I imagine `paste0("C:/Temp/", ifelse(condition, "", "Approved/"), "abc.pdf")` would work just fine.

Comment: I'd like to use `file.path` function. In other cases `file.path` function helped a lot when working in other operating systems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a dynamic-length character vector with `if (condition) value`:

```
f = function(cond) do.call(file.path, 
  as.list(c("C:/Temp", if (cond) "Approved", "abc.pdf"))
)

f(TRUE)
# [1] "C:/Temp/Approved/abc.pdf"
f(FALSE)
# [1] "C:/Temp/abc.pdf"
```

This works because `if (FALSE) value` becomes `NULL` and nulls are dropped in atomic vectors:

```
c(1, NULL, 2)
# [1] 1 2
```

Comment: Perfect! I'll use: `fileName <- do.call(file.path, as.list(c("C:/Temp", if (!condition) "Approved", "abc.pdf")))`. Thanks!